# Find the poet in the poem

Tags: riddle, poetry

> I sit on a circle; I jump on a square.
>
> My clothes are tailor-made, but don't really fit.
>
> My shorter cousin's enemy is a lamp that is lit.
>
> If you wrote down my name, I wouldn't know it was there.
>
> Herald my going with sadness and coming with joy.
>
> But children, please remember that I carry a tool, not a toy.

Ignoring the terrible poetry, (my bad haha) can you identify the speaker in this poem wannabe?

OK, it's been quite a while. Here's a hint:

> The author's name/title is the same as a card name in the mobile game Clash Royale. There's a list here: https://statsroyale.com/cards. You can see the names by hovering over the cards with your mouse. If you are on mobile, just look up "List of Clash Royale cards". **The actual riddle is not related to this game; the game just provided what I though was a good hint.**

That should narrow it down some without making it too obvious, I think.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.SE! There's no rule for when to add hints, everyone around here seems to do it differently. I let things sit for ages... but I am an 'extremist' :-)

Comment: @Brandon_J So the answer isn't an actual poet, and the clues all relate to a specific mobile phone game? If so, that might explain why nobody answered yet...

Comment: No, the answer has **nothing at all** to do with the mobile game. I just happened to be playing the game and noticed that there was a card with the same name as my poet, so I thought it could make a good hint. I fixed the hint to prevent confusion.

Comment: Hint doesn't work on mobile

Comment: Drat. Just look up "list of clash royale cards" on your device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial answer:

> Knight of the Round Table

I sit on a circle; I jump on a square.

> (1) Referring to chess: 
> if the original position of the knight is white, it lands on a black square after a move, and vice versa
>  (2) And perhaps Circle--> Round Table?

My clothes are tailor-made, but don't really fit.

> Knights' shirts are loose, see this: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Medieval-Renaissance-Loose-Men-Knight-Shirts-Tops-Viking-Lace-Up-V-Neck-Tops-UK-/372487449947

My shorter cousin's enemy is a lamp that is lit.

> Shorter cousin = Night (Shorter word length, same pronunciation) 
> Night, "enemy" of light

If you wrote down my name, I wouldn't know it was there.

> perhaps this?  [see here](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=NJbPHs4rHD8C&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=knight%20name%20wont%20know%20it%20was%20there&source=bl&ots=7bNxPyMrXr&sig=rq4Z0pOvkDaeAsca4yjB70i_6jQ&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjig7Clyc7fAhUMfXAKHSbECoEQ6AEwA3oECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=You%20have%20another%20name%2C%20a%20secret%20name%2C%20one%20that%20you%20won't%20know&f=false)
>  **UPDATE:** Very possible: [this](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=luflXjz8tqYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=The%20Book%20of%20Fate&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinrK2Eq9TfAhUHdt4KHaZlAeYQ6AEIPzAD#v=onepage&q=wrote%20down%20eight%20people's%20names%2C%20then%20camouflaged%20it%20with%20doodles&f=false)

Herald my going with sadness and coming with joy.

> **Old guesses:**
> Referring to night again? Night going = day, need to work 
>  night coming = playtime for many = joy? 
>  **OR**
>  Knight going = war = sad, Knight coming = victory = joy?
> ---
>  **Actual:**
> Simply representing the idea of heraldry, according to OP

But children, please remember that I carry a tool, not a toy.

> a lance/ sword is a weapon, not a toy

Also Possible:

> Sir Lancelot due to lance in last line, "TITLE" in hint, [this](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=NJbPHs4rHD8C&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=knight%20name%20wont%20know%20it%20was%20there&source=bl&ots=7bNxPyMrXr&sig=rq4Z0pOvkDaeAsca4yjB70i_6jQ&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjig7Clyc7fAhUMfXAKHSbECoEQ6AEwA3oECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=You%20have%20another%20name%2C%20a%20secret%20name%2C%20one%20that%20you%20won't%20know&f=false), and he being a knight?

Comment: You almost got it! The second-to-last line was just the idea of heraldry. The first and fourth lines still have a bit more for you to get. Tip for the fourth line - think actual medieval knight.

Comment: @Brandon_J edited how about this?

Comment: edited, pretty sure it's this, or is it not? ;)